# Can't retrieve cookie in vueJS frontend from NestJS backend. Doing Oauth authentication

Tags: cookies, oauth-2.0, frontend, nestjs, backend

I'm trying to setup an Oauth authentication but I can't retrieve any cookie in the frontend. Here is my stack:

- vueJS (frontend)
- nestJS (backend)
- passport (Oauth)
- prisma (ORM)
- postgreSQL (DB)
- vuetify (UI lib)
- vue router

I'm also running everything in a multi container docker env with:

- frontend: localhost on port 8080
- backend: localhost on port 3000

Here is the flow of my authentication for now:

Frontend "log with..." button -> backend /login controller -> Oauth API -> strategy validation function (here i get access to user info) -> validation and add in db -> generating JWT token with user.ID -> backend /callback function -> redirect to frontend.

Some of the config files:

vite.config.ts:

```js
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    host: true,
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://backend:3000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      }
    }
  },
```

backend main.ts:

```js
  app.use(cookieParser())
  app.use(passport.initialize())

  app.enableCors({
    origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
  });
  await app.listen(3000);
```

I'll to follow the same flow as explained before with functions definition:

loginForm.vue:

`window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8080/api/auth/42'`
This is inside a method that i run when clicking on a button. I use window.location.href because i couldn't use AJAX as said here (https://blog.devgenius.io/why-is-my-fetch-request-to-oauth-server-being-blocked-by-cors-c8bdadb92b30)

auth.controller.ts:

```js
    @Get('42')
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('42'))
    async login() {
        console.log("entry")
        passport.authenticate('42')
    }
```

This is where my href point to. As described in passport I use authenticate('42') a first time to make the call to the Oauth API.

school.strategy.ts:

```js
@Injectable()
export class FortyTwoStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, '42') {
    constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {
        super({
            clientID: process.env["42_CLIENT_ID"],
            clientSecret: process.env["42_CLIENT_SECRET"],
            callbackURL: process.env["42_CALLBACK_URL"]
        });
    }

    async validate(accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, profile: any, done: Function): Promise<any> {
        console.log("PROFILE: ", profile.id )
        const token = await this.authService.validateUser(profile);
        if (!token) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

this is the entire strategy class with the validate function.

auth.service.ts:

```js
    async validateUser(profile: any): Promise< any > {
        console.log('______________________validate_USER_____________________')
        const user = await this.prisma.user.upsert({
            where: { 
                name: profile.username
            },
            update: {},
            create: {
                name: profile.username,
                password: profile.id
            }
        })
        if (user) {
            console.log("User validated: ", user)
            const token = await this.signToken({id: user.id})
            return { token };
        }
        console.log("User not validated")
        return null;
    };

    async signToken(payload: any): Promise<any> {
        const secret = process.env.JWT_KEY;
        const token = await this.jwtService.signAsync(payload,
            {
                expiresIn: "7d",
                secret: secret
            });
            return token;
    }
```

Note here that I put the profile.id in the password field just for testing purpose, I didn't change the prisma.schema yet. But its of no use for now.

auth.service.ts:

```js
    @Get('42/callback')
    @UseGuards(AuthGuard('42'))
    async callback(@Req() req: Request, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response) {
        console.log("______________________callback__________________")
        passport.authenticate('42', { failureRedirect: '/fail' })
        res.cookie('userData', req.user, {httpOnly: true, secure: false})
        console.log("RES: ", res.getHeaders());
        return res
        .status(302)
        .redirect('http://localhost:8080/profil')
    }
```

This is the Oauth callback function, note that req.user is populated by passport with the return of the validate function. So here req.user = token from the previous function.
Also here is the output of the `console.log("RES: ", res.getHeaders());`

```
backend   | RES:  [Object: null prototype] {
backend   |   'x-powered-by': 'Express',
backend   |   'access-control-allow-origin': 'http://localhost:8080',
backend   |   vary: 'Origin',
backend   |   'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
backend   |   'set-cookie': 'userData=j%3A%7B%22token%22%3A%22eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MywiaWF0IjoxNjk1ODIxNzIzLCJleHAiOjE2OTY0MjY1MjN9.irnsdN85srkAimWgkpfI7vivNg8cF35bPE0Axr-pluU%22%7D; Path=/; HttpOnly'
backend   | }
```

Now back in the frontend where it redirect. I use vue-cookies to get the cookies.
ProfilView.vue:

```js
    mounted() {
      const cookies = this.$cookies.get('userData');
      console.log("COOKIE: ", cookies);
    },
```

The console.log gives me `COOKIE: null`

And here is a screen of the firefox devtools network tab.

[callback redirection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fflVA.png)

[GET /profil call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Offve.png)

The problem is that i can't get to the response as I would normally do in an axios request. I don't really now if it's the right way, but for now it is not working properly.

I've just realized writing this that the set-cookie in response header is present in the callback redirection, but the other GET call to /profil doesnt have it. I don't really understand what is happening here, if someone could explain and help me resolve my issues.

Thanks !